# operator !! in Javascript (angular)

Tags: javascript, angular, syntax, operators

I met this line of code and have no idea what '!!' is:

```
isLoggedIn() {
    return !!this.getJwtToken();
  }
```

can anyone please help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This notation is used to get the Boolean value of a variable.
In your case it would return false if `this.getJwtToken();` is either `undefined`, `null`, `false` or simply an `""` empty string.